# Rewrite my angularJS script to support localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I've been trying to rewrite a shoppingcart script in angularJS with localStorage support so they array will survive a refresh or switch to another page. However I cant seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```
<script>
angular.module('appname', ['ngStorage'])
    .controller('CartController', ['$scope', function CartController($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {

    if ($localStorage.items === undefined) {
        $localStorage.items = [];
    }

    $scope.addToCart = function(index, title, desc, price) {
        var found = false;
        angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(items) {
            if (items.id  === index) {
                items.quantity++;
                found = true;
            }
        });
        if (!found) {
            $localStorage.items.push(angular.extend({id: index, title: title, quantity: 1, price: price}, index));
        }
    };

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $localStorage.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
}])
</script>
```

When i'm replacing all the $localStorage.items for $scope.items the website works fine but without the localStorage support. What am I doing wrong?

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
>       at new CartController (page.php:604)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4604)
>       at T.instance (angular.js:9855)
>       at u (angular.js:8927)
>       at g (angular.js:8226)
>       at g (angular.js:8229)
>       at angular.js:8106
>       at angular.js:1696
>       at m.$eval (angular.js:16820)
>       at m.$apply (angular.js:16920)

**Update 1**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appname">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-controller="CartController">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="addToCart(1,'x','y','5.00');">Toevoegen</a>

<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
{{item.title}}
{{item.price | currency:"&euro;"}}
{{item.price * item.quantity | currency:"&euro;"}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
angular.module('appname', ['ngStorage'])
    .controller('CartController', ['$scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage', function CartController($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {

    if ($localStorage.items === undefined) {
        $localStorage.items = [];
    }

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $localStorage.items.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.addToCart = function(index, title, desc, price) {
        var found = false;
        angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(items) {
            if (items.id  === index) {
                items.quantity++;
                found = true;
            }
        });
        if (!found) {
            $localStorage.items.push(angular.extend({id: index, title: title, quantity: 1, price: price}, index));
        }
    };
  }])
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you console.log($localStorage) for me?  Is $localStorage the name of a service you added?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with ngStorage, but have always just built a LocalStorage service that is very easy to do and works fine.

Comment: I've built my own LocalStorage service, like @Dave M, the API is very simple, so it may be worth just bootstrapping your own.

Comment: sadly i'm not that experienced with javascript just yet. Just started with AngularJS and javascript

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    .controller('CartController', ['$scope', function CartController($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
```

with

```
    .controller('CartController', ['$scope', '$localStorage', '$sessionStorage', function CartController($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
```

These variables aren't injected in your example. Try using a tool like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to make sure this doesn't happen again!

Comment: Tried that but still have an error.

    Error: $injector:unpr
    Unknown Provider
    Unknown provider: $scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorageProvider <- $scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage <- CartController

Comment: He's right though, you definitely need to do this in the first place.  Now you can find the next error.

Comment: Do you have ngStorage included in the page?

Comment: Yep I have. Tried local and also from the internet. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js

Comment: From that error, it looks like you may be passing in only one string to the controller? i.e. '$scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage'; each of these has to be separate

Comment: To add stuff i'm using the following:

`<body ng-controller="CartController"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="addToCart(1,'x','y','5.00');">Add</a></body>`

So far this worked great with $scope. I'm fairly new to javascript and angularJS so might be making beginner mistakes with parsing variables into a function.

Comment: He is talking about the dependence injection on the controller definition. Could you update this part on you question?

Comment: Sorry for asking but what is "the dependence injection on the controller definition"? I've made an update with the most recent version of what the script looks like right now.

Comment: I can't comment on your answer below, but just to explain, this is effectively the same solution as I posted, which was probably mistakenly transcribed on your part. The array listing the dependencies in the controller is used so that the code can still identify the dependencies if the code is minified (renaming the function variables)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing the following:

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', ['ngStorage']);
appname.controller('CartController', function($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
```

Now it works as expected.